# USB Type-C pins' designation

Tags: serial, usb-c

I am trying to design a USB to Serial converter featuring CH340C IC and I'm a bit concerned whether I have correctly hooked up the SBU, DP/DN, and Shell pins. Is there any chance that I did everything right?
[image]

Comment: There is a chance but we don't know based on your schematic. Where are the nodes connected that are otherwise unused, the 5V, VCC, 3V3, TXD and RXD? There is a good chance that you have them incorrect, and it also depends if this is a self-powered or bus-powered device, so these schematics are not enough.

Comment: There are four VBUS and four GND pins on a USB-C port, you should connect them all.

Comment: @Finbarr The connector has four VBUS and GND pins, but this connector provides two PCB pins for them. They are internally connected (unless it is a non-compliant connector).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The USB connector is fine.

You may want some lossy capacitance, a TVS, or both, on the 5V connection.  Lossy as in, having significant ESR; an electrolytic is a typical choice.  A ceramic with external resistor is another option (say 1uF + 1Ω; this could be added in series with C1).  (Pay attention to the USB maximum attached load capacitance specification.)

A TVS both handles inrush/overshoot on the supply, and can provide protection for the data lines as well when a combination data line clamp + TVS type like NUP4202, D1213A-04S, etc. is chosen. This isn't a high priority (the data lines are afforded some physical ESD protection already, by way of the shielded connector: a spark very likely jumps to the shell rather than any contacts), but offers a cheap and effective boost to robustness.

TVS arrays may also be wise on the serial side, assuming those are subject to hazards like grubby operator hands touching them.  (...Me. They're my grubby hands all over my projects.  I use safe ESD practices, but there's always the exception, and it's nice to have protection in case.)  These should be referenced to GND and VCC (or whatever supply the CH340C uses for the serial side).

Always check the [CH340C datasheet](https://www.mpja.com/download/35227cpdata.pdf) for recommended supply connections, of course.

The `V3` pin likely means it has an internal LDO, which could obviate U2.  At a glance, it doesn't look like they provide any characteristics on it, though.  As a design matter, I would want to see a specified current range for the pin before using it this way.  You may experiment with it if you like (essentially, the professional equivalent of this is *qualification testing*).

Pins 2 and 4 should be tied on U2; a polygon/pour can be attached to these pads to improve heat dissipation.

U2 requires a lossy output capacitor (C2) for stable regulation; check [the datasheet](http://www.advanced-monolithic.com/pdf/ds1117.pdf).  They recommend 22uF tantalum; likely in the range of 0.2-1Ω ESR, which can be substituted with similar values of ceramic plus external resistor if you prefer.  (Use an 0805 or larger, X7R or X5R, ceramic chip for this.)

As a rule, I shop for regulators that (a) specify what types of capacitor they are stable with, (b) what range of capacitance and ESR they are stable over, and (c) specify GND/ADJ pin current including in dropout.  This particular part does only one of these, just barely; I would be skeptical of designing it in.  To be fair, it appears to be a clone of a classic design (LM1117 low*ish* dropout regulator), which is known to be somewhat temperamental (i.e., do obey the C<sub>OUT</sub> "recommendation"; it's less a recommendation and more a requirement..!), and not known to draw substantial GND current (hence, being *usable at all* as an adjustable regulator in the classic (LM317 style) way).

As a matter of schematic notation, please avoid multiple names (aliases) on nets, and symbol shapes: it confuses the reader, it's more things to remember, etc.  The port symbol by the resistors is also redundant when the `VCC` power symbol is right there; they could be bussed for example.  Just neatens things up, simple enough.

Likewise, components and labels should be oriented for best reading, and signal flow; U2 might be edited for a less physically-representative shape, say putting pins 2 and 4 adjacent, and putting VIN and VOUT on left and right sides.

Comment: That is incorrect. The resistors are not there to just trigger out 5V. The resistors are there to detect what is plugged in and in which orientation, to know if the port should be in UFP or DFP mode, to determine if the data pins should be set to host or device mode, and to give power or not just depends on the mode, prior to USB enumeration. Also any USB compliant device, even self-powered one, must not try to enumerate with host if it does not receive VBUS on the port. This is so incorrect on so many levels.

Comment: Oh yeah, UFP/DFP, thanks for the reminder! Could you enumerate what "many" other levels are "incorrect"? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry I was a bit overreacting, only on two levels really. 1) Resistors needed to configure port mode/direction and to trigger 5V out 2) 5V must come out from host to device as device must not communicate unless host sends 5V. Which by the way means that the CH340 is really only suitable for bus powered devices, it does not easily fit into self-powered devices (datasheet suggests shorting the supplies with 1 ohm resistor, that's garbage).

Comment: Sorry, I believe I made a mistake by not showing the full diagram. I'll update my question with the schematics that I have.

Comment: Attached is the full schematics.

Answer (score 2):

The adapter should work. There is nothing inherently wrong in the schematics.

But this is almost identical to other adapters that do the same thing and you can buy these or even adapters with better chips than CH340, so you should consider buying if you need reliable adapters.